# MacBook Pro Touch Bar won't respond

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, touch-bar

The Touch Bar on my MacBook Pro is actually reflecting changes depending on the software context and showing the right buttons. However, it won't respond to my inputs.

I've tried to reset it via Terminal and all the potential solutions that I found on the Internet, but unfortunately none of them worked.

Could you please help me out to make it operational again?

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: What is the version of macOS running on your MacBook?

Comment: Thanks @NimeshNeema, it's Mojave, 10.14.1

Comment: You can update to the current public release i.e. macOS Mojave 10.14.5 and see if fixed the issue.

Comment: I know it's hard to know, but do you think that'll fix it, @NimeshNeema?

Comment: I don’t know if it would, but it could and it should.

Comment: Thanks @NimeshNeema, I'll try. If you post this as an answer, I will happily mark it as the valid answer as soon as I try it.

Comment: @NimeshNeema, it worked, thanks! if you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently running macOS Mojave 10.14.1 which is among the initial releases, and is generally buggier.

Try updating to the current public release 10.14.5, which has addressed a lot of bug fixes. This could potentially fix the issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You can check there is any issue with the hardware components which are connected to the touch bar by using <kbd>fn</kbd> key. Soon after you hit the key that should display in the touch bar. In that case you can decide this issue is either software or hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks @Binoyya, FN keys are appearing in the Touch Bar as soon as I hit the button, however they won't work if I hit them, I am afraid.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you since yesterday @dev. Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: @ChristopheGeers just updated it and that fixed the issue, hope it works for you mate!

Comment: Thanks @dev. But I found out I had a crack in my touch bar. It's a hairline fracture and I didn't notice it at first. Everything left of the crack still works (escape only) and everything to the right doesn't work anymore as the signal is no longer transmitted. So in my case it's the hardware .... and apparently very expensive to have fixed.